# Simple Android application going OOM

Tags: java, android, memory, memory-management, out-of-memory

I have a simple application, collecting and showing Wifi scan results with a few extra features, no intense CPU/RAM usage.

Problem is while my Thread is running (This thread scan and outputs results via a ExpandableListView), my memory is being filled up avg 70Mb at a time.

I noticed when reviewing the memory dump that my objects I create exist after they are cleared.

e.g. a simple example of what I have implemented

```
private ExpandableListAdapter returnList(Context context, String[] APList) {
    if (bLogging) { //Assume true
        ArrayList<String> List = new ArrayList<>();
        foreach (AccessPoint ap: APList){
            //code initilializing and assigning param variables
            List.add(new AP(param1, param2, param3))
        }
        return (new ExpandableListAdapter(context, List));
    }
}
```

*Please do not worry about any syntax,etc issues, this is just for understanding of my problem.*

This piece of code is run by a `Thread`, sleeping every `500ms` to rescan

In this example, after `returnList()` has finished executing, the `ArrayList<> List`, `new AP(param...)` will remain as objects, taking up memory.

My thread loop is defined by:

```
//code before

t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            handler = new Handler(context.getMainLooper());
            while (!bStopThread) {
                ThreadCounter++;

                handler.post(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        if (bSafe) {
                            initWiFiArrays();  //AccessPoint Objects are created as shown in example
                            CreateSetAdapter(); //Custom ExpandableListAdapter is created, but declared and instantiated within the method
                            threadRefresh.setText("# Refreshed Times : " + String.valueOf(ThreadCounter));
                            writeResultsToFile();
                        } else
                            stopScan();
                    }
                });
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(scanInterval);
                } catch (Exception x) {
                    x.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    });
t.start();

//code after
```

**UPDATE:**

I resorted to clearing globally declared Lists and a scanResultCollection which contain +/- 9 items, this decreases memory taken up by 40Mb.

Comment: Why wouldn't they remain in memory when `List` is referenced in your `return` statement?

Comment: Apologies if I misunderstand, but java has garbage collection, since this method is has finished its purpose, it will be cleaned up, this it will "not be in memory" in the sense of me easily accessing it.

Comment: You are "*leaking*" your `local` variable to the outside scope.  While there is a *live* reference to an object, it's not a subject to garbage collection.

Comment: ok, so on the first run, there will be a local variable going "out", but what happens in the second and third, etc. Will this "live" not have its pointer replaced by the second and  third run of the created local variable. In other words, will the 1st run not be collected when its parent gets a new object?

Answer (score 1):

use crashlytics library..this would help you know from where memory leaks take place in your app

Comment: What is the relevance to the actual question?

Comment: I am using Android Studio, I'm thinking it mught be a bug, I have come across a few bugs, where booleans are not being changed, etc. but i shall try it, thanks